# Php and Mysql date in seconds are different for current time stamp

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

using `TO_SECONDS(DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s' ) )` I am getting current time in seconds but at the same time when i try to find time in seconds by server using `strtotime(strftime("%F %T %p"))`  it's different.
eg: mysql gives 63657226218 seconds whereas php unix time is 1489986896.

Thanx in advance

Comment: You cant to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP no TO_SECONDS

Answer (score 0):

TO_SECONDS Given a date or datetime expr, returns a the number of seconds since the year **0**. Not 1970!

You want to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

Comment: And the fact that it is entirely plausible to have PHP and MySQL set on different timezones

Comment: For me unix_timestamp and time() are working to compare two times from database and current time Thanx for your Guidance